# Triangular range counting query in poly-logarithmic time

Tags: ds.data-structures, computational-geometry, range-searching

What is the minimal space requirement for 
triangular range counting queries in plane 
if one wants to process each query in poly-logarithmic time?

In [Goswami et al, 2004] 
they preprocess the points to create a data structure in $O(n^2)$ time and space
achieving $O(\log n)$ query time for triangular range counting.

Is it the best known result till date?

---

References:
Partha P. Goswamia, Sandip Dasb, Subhas C. Nandy,
"[Triangular range counting query in 2D and its application in finding k nearest neighbors of a line segment](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092577210400029X)", 2004

Comment: Yes.  Even for half-space  queries we do not know how to do anything better, and it seems unlikely that one could do better.

Comment: Na, I am too lazy to figure out the right refs. But the following would have the right refs somewhere:
http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/pdf/survey-tr.pdf

Comment: I have seen this survey before. This is years old. I wonder if anything came up after that or even after the reference I mentioned, something which proves a lower bound.